# RocketChat call webService on android client

Tags: android, rocket.chat

since 3 days ago i'm trying to find which file or implementation on android client is for RocketChat REST web services, for example:

```
/api/v1/login
```

unfortunately i cant find implementation classes for them to learn that for developing client application, Thanks in advance

Comment: First, you have to set up the server-side code.
Then point to your server.
e.g
In my case, I set up the Rocket chat code on my own server, 
here is how login URL looks
Url: http://myserverurl/api/v1/login 
Method: Post:
Body :{
 "user":"ummer",
 "password":"Ummer33"
}
Header: Content_type= application/json

Answer (score 0):

The currently Android App (version 1.0.25) is not using REST API for authentication (or any other method). It only uses Web Socket for that. Rocket.Chat is working in a Kotlin SDK that will implement this REST API calls: https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.Kotlin.SDK.